# Openx 2.8.10 local image/banner destination url dont work

Tags: javascript, html, openx, banner-ads

I created a banner of type "banner Local" on my openx.

In the destination url i put `http://www.delphifontes.com.br/?pagina=pparceiros.`

A simple page in my own website, but when i click on it, it takes me to:

```
http://www.delphifontes.com.br/openx/www/delivery/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.delphifontes.com.br%2F%3Fpagina%3Dpparceiros
```

Please, how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: has no code, its a simple local banner, with a image uploaded via openx interface, but destination not work

Answer (score 1):

You should check your openx site configuation file, located in the openx **/var** folder. This file is named **yourdomain.conf.php**, so your's should be named **www.delphifontes.com.br.conf.php**

This file contains a couple of sections, each starts with a section name in brackets, i.e. [file], [webpath], ... - similar to the good old Windows 3 ini-files.

I assume, the **[file]** section is somewho missing the value for the **click** script, a line which reads:

**click="ck.php"**

As a result, the rendering engine of openx fails to build correct click-Urls. The complete "file" section should usually look like:

```
[file]
click="ck.php"
conversionvars="tv.php"
content="ac.php"
conversion="ti.php"
conversionjs="tjs.php"
flash="fl.js"
google="ag.php"
frame="afr.php"
image="ai.php"
js="ajs.php"
layer="al.php"
log="lg.php"
popup="apu.php"
view="avw.php"
xmlrpc="axmlrpc.php"
local="alocal.php"
frontcontroller="fc.php"
singlepagecall="spc.php"
spcjs="spcjs.php"
xmlrest="ax.php"
```